# Нумерация строк в результате от grep

Tags: unix, grep, linux

Всем привет.

Как можно пронумеровать строки, которые получаются в результате поиска строк от *grep*?

Например, я ввёл: `grep "mystring" file.txt`. На выходе я получаю, что-то типа:

> My home - it's **mystring**
>   Dont **mysqtring**
>   Jony **mysqtring** Jastin

А мне нужно:

> 1. My home - it's **mystring**
> 2. Dont **mysqtring**
> 3. Jony **mysqtring** Jastin

Comment: А ты случайно не знаешь, как закрыть вопрос?

Comment: @FordMustang, под вопросом есть ссылки [править],[закрыть], ...

Может очков пока не хватает? Тогда я могу закрыть.

Comment: @avp Да, если можно)

Comment: Хм, а какой смысл закрывать вопрос? Вдруг кто-то придумает ещё один хороший ответ?

Comment: Вопрос решен)

Comment: @VladD, мне кажется, у Вас самого достаточно полномочий. Хотите переоткрыть - открывайте.

Comment: @avp: у меня нету ответа лучше вашего, так что переоткрывать вроде бы не нужно. Просто я не вполне понимаю, какой профит от закрытия вопроса для кого бы то ни было, вот мне и стало интересно.

Comment: @VladD, я тоже не понимаю сути этих заморочек. Автор вопроса попросил (а у него очков для этого действия (вот уж дурь!) не хватает), вот я и закрыл.

А задайте этот вопрос (про профит) ХэшКоду (наверное на Мете).

Comment: @avp: задал: http://meta.hashcode.ru/questions/664/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep "mystring" file.txt | cat -n
```

Answer (score 2):

Более правильно будет

```
grep -n "mystring" file.txt
```

и выполнится быстрее

Comment: Как я понимаю, в таком случае выведутся номера строк в искомом файле, а это не совсем то, что нужно, но все равно спасибо.

Comment: да, вы правы )